# Merging two dataframes on some overlapping columns while keeping non-overlapping columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I currently have two dataframes:

```
df1:

     col1    col2   col3   col4
 0  Apple   store1    1      3
 1  Tree    store2    1      3
 2  Banana  store3    2      4
 3  Card    store4    2      4 ...

df2:

     col1    col2   col3   col4   col5   col6
 0  Apple   store1    1      3     123    50
 1  Tree    store2    1      3     451    32
 2  Mango   store2    2      4     313    15
 3  Guava   store5    2      4     113     9
```

What I want to do is to merge df1 and df2 together if the values in the first 4 columns are identical, but I want to append the values of col5 and col6 onto the merged dataframe. So the ideal output would be:

```
merged_df:

     col1    col2   col3   col4   col5   col6
 0  Apple   store1    1      3     123    50
 1  Tree    store2    1      3     451    32 ...
```

When I tried to merge I get NaN values returned on col5 and col6 on the merged dataframe. Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want an inner merge. By default, common columns will be used for merging:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, how='inner')

print(res)

    col1    col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0  Apple  store1     1     3   123    50
1   Tree  store2     1     3   451    32
```

Answer (score 0):

you need ,

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
[out]
#col1   col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
#Apple  store1  1       3       123     50
#Tree   store2  1       3       451     32
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complicated example with multiple join keys. Only the keys appearing in left and right are present (the intersection), since how='inner' by default.

From the pandas docs :

> result = pd.merge(left, right, on=['key1', 'key2'])

```
result = pd.merge(def1, df2, on=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
```